# How can I copy the values of a variable to another variable in a NetCDF but not the dimension?

Tags: netcdf, netcat, netcdf4, nco

I have 2 dimensions `X1, X2`

And 3 variables `V1(X1), V2(X2), V3(X3)`

I want to copy the *values* of V2 to V1. But keep the dimensions as it is.

If I do:

```
ncap2 -s "V2=V1*1" in.nc out.nc
```

the dimensions become `V1(X2), V2(X2), V3(X3)`

How can I retain the original dimension of V1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an unusual request. One solution is to follow the step you already have with one more command to append the values you want back into the original variable. Here lon and ilev are both the same size, but with different underlying dimensions:

```
ncap2 -O -v -s 'lon=ilev' ~/in.nc ~/foo.nc # make lon a copy of ilev
ncks -A -C -v lon ~/foo.nc ~/in.nc # append lon back into itself
```